# Zooming Out Breaks Navigation CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

I have a Wordpress site [here](http://rainleader.com) that looks great at 100% zoom. If, however, you zoom out, the layout breaks (specifically the logo and navigation).

How do I correct this?

See screenshots:

Normal:

[image: Normal]

Partly Zoomed Out:

[image: Partly Zoomed Out]

Fully Zoomed Out:

[image: Fully Zoomed Out]

Comment: I'm guessing your navbar has a static width in pixels? When things are scaled down, the browser can't understand fractional pixels, so it discards them (either by rounding or truncating).

Comment: Also, you should post your html/css that is pertinent to the menu itself.

Comment: PPS, Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Cvw/

Comment: @Shmiddty: The navigation uses a width defined in ems (35.7em). Is it better to use 100% instead? Also, would an issue like that cause the massive shift in positioning (also in ems)?

Comment: It might be as simple as defining `box-sizing:border-box` on your menu items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using % width for images might help. Also, using ems or % for the nav elements like width, font-size, and paddings and/or margins would be a good idea. Experiment and see what works best!

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the positioning is affected for the navigation, though? That doesn't use an image.

Comment: What do you think about centering the logo? Should I use margins rather than position to center it?